# Kafka confluent JDBC connector invalid value

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I used kafka jdbc confluent connector 3.x to get data from Oracle and publish it to Kafka server.

The property file configuration is here below.

```
name=demo-jdbc-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc://db_config  
table.whitelist=Table_test
tasks.max=1 
mode=incrementing 
incrementing.column.name=TEST_ID
topic.prefix=jdbc-source-
```

While running it getting an error like:

```
> Invalid value io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector for
> configuration connector.class: Class
> io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JDBC connector JAR can't be found by Kafka Connect.

Are you using [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/) itself, or the [JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/) alongside your existing Kafka deployment? In the former the paths will be set up automagically. If the latter you'll need to make sure that `kafka-connect-jdbc-3.3.0.jar` is on your CLASSPATH (or use the [`plugin.path` configuration option](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins) on your Connect worker config)

Comment: I'm using  JDBC connector , which one will be the best way ? using confluent platform or jdbc connector !

Comment: The Confluent Platform includes as part of it the JDBC connector. So you can either just use Confluent Platform, or you can use Kafka from elsewhere and download the JDBC connector separately.